# symfony route fails to match its own generated uri

Tags: php, symfony, reverse, routes

I define a route using the Symfony Routing Component

Using this route i generate an uri. `'https://domain.tl/login'`

Upon navigating to that uri, the UrlMatcher fails to match and throws.

```
// $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'https://domain.tl/login' 

// old situation
//$request_context = new RequestContext($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// problem solved:
$protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? 'http':'https';
$request_context = new RequestContext($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$request_context->setScheme($protocol);



$routes = new RouteCollection;

// should match: https://domain.tl/login
$routes->add('login', new Route('login', array(), array(), array(), '', array('https')));

// reverse routing
$base_uri = new RequestContext;
$base_uri->setHost($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

$generator = new UrlGenerator($routes, $base_uri);

var_dump($generator->generate('login')); // gives: https://domain.tl/login

try
{
    $matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $request_context);
    $matcher->match($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // throws

    die('match');
}
catch(\Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException $ex)
{
    die('no match');
}
```

I really struggle figuring out how to debug this without diving in the Routing Component code.
Hope i am missing something obvious :)

**edit**: The route does work without the restriction on https. This restriction is needed though.

**edit2**: it works! i implemented the fix in the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, the problem you sad only on https, but if you check the value for the HTTP_HOST that don't say it's a http or https. I'm sure, it will work without the https restriction

Comment: Yes it works without the restriction. But that's not what i want/need.

Comment: could not edit my previous comment cause of the 5 minutes rule. While editing said comment i understood what you meant and tested it. It works now!